# expanding a dataclass of type list by an element

Tags: python, dictionary, python-dataclasses

I have defined a dataclass which is a list and I want to expand it:

```
@dataclass
class ShoppingCart:
    item_id: list = None

@dataclass
class Purchase:
    items: dict = ShoppingCart

@dataclass
class Item:
    price: int = 0
    name: str = ""
```

so later on I put an item in the Shoppingcart:

```
if getattr(inst_of_Purchase, inst_of_ShoppingCart) == None: ##no item in cart
    setattr(inst_of_Purchase, inst_of_ShoppingCart, inst_of_Item)
else: ## add an item
    ***
```

What is the correct Syntax to append an item to get a structure like this:

```
Purchase_1: {ShoppingCart_1: [item_1, item_2 ...], 
             ShoppingCart_2: [item_123, item_2 ...]...}
```

Comment: `getattr(Purchase, ShoppingCart)` - I think you're getting confused about how dataclasses work. Even though technically you do declare them as class variables (i.e. scoped at the class level), the `@dataclass` decorator works to ensure they are actually *instance* attributes at runtime. So in this example, the correct syntax would actually be `getattr(instance_of_Purchase, instance_of_ShoppingCart)`, though you can actually use dot `.` operator instead of `getattr`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I did not pay enough attention when copy/paste my example code. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would declare the models, using forward references so it's a bit easier to see the nested structure (top-down instead of bottom-up). If you want to go with a bottom-up approach as you initially had, you can swap the order you define the dataclasses and switch `List['ShoppingCart']` to just `List[ShoppingCart]` for example.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List


@dataclass
class Purchase:
    carts: List['ShoppingCart'] = None


@dataclass
class ShoppingCart:
    # If you want default value to be an empty list:
    #  item: List['Item'] = dataclasses.field(default_factory=list)
    items: List['Item'] = None


@dataclass
class Item:
    price: int = 0
    name: str = ""
```

Then if we need to add items to a new purchase:

```py
my_purchase = Purchase()

if my_purchase.carts is None:  # no item in cart
    item_1 = Item(name='first item')
    item_2 = Item(2, 'second item')

    my_cart = ShoppingCart(items=[item_1, item_2])
    my_purchase.carts = [my_cart]

else: ## add an item
    ...

print(my_purchase)
# Purchase(carts=[ShoppingCart(items=[Item(price=0, name='first item'), Item(price=2, name='second item')])])
```

Note that if you're on Python 3.9+ (I wasn't sure if you are) you can remove the `typing.List` import, and use the built in `list`, as standard collections now support subscripted types. So for example, taken from the above:

```
carts: List['ShoppingCart'] = None
```

would become just (without the `typing` import):

```
carts: list['ShoppingCart'] = None
```

Comment: Yep, I just have. let me know if that helps or you'd like to clarify anything else.

Comment: Still fighting with implementation. But the question is answered.